# Custom buttons in full calender

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, alpine.js

I am trying to add custom buttons to the full calendar as per the UI requirement. I want to add and subtract one year on right and left custom buttons click. But the problem is when I call this. calendar('prevYear') on click functions, it throws an error this. calendar is not a function as I am accessing the calendar property inside the calendar init phase. How can implement this click function?
I am using alpine.js to initialize the full calendar and define its option. Is there any way to only change the icon of left and right but the function is automatically added by the full calender ?

```
<div
     x-data="{
         calendar: null,
         events: [
             
         ],
        
         init() {
             this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(this.$refs.calendar, {
                 initialDate: '2022-12-19',
                 initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                 selectable: true,
                 unselectAuto: false,
                 editable: true,
                 customButtons: {
                  prevYear: {
                    text: '<<',
                    click: function() {
                     this.calendar('prevYear')
                     
                    }
                  },
                  nextYear: {
                    text: '>>',
                    click: function() {
                     this.calendar('nextYear')
                      
                      
                    }
                  }
                },
                 headerToolbar: {
                  left: 'prevYear',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'nextYear'
                },
                views: {
                  dayGridMonth: { 
                    titleFormat: {  year: 'numeric' }
                    
                  }
                },
                
                
             })
    
            
             this.calendar.render()
             
           
         },
        
     }"
    >
     <div x-ref="calendar"></div>
    
     
    </div>
```